# Creating Pandas Pivot Table or Transpose in Python without Aggregate Function

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm trying to crosstabulate a dataset to analyse sequences like web browsing behaviour:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CustId' : [111,111,222,333,333,333], 
                'Page': ['A','B','A','A','B','C']
              })
```

For each CustId, i would like to end up with a cross tab of CustID vs Page:

[image]

The Dataset is already ordered as i'm interested in analysing the sequence. In fact the next step will be to perform counts of combinations i.e. how many CustIds follow path A|B, how many A|, how many A|B|C

I've had a go at doing this and the closest i could get to was:

```
df2=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['CustId'],values=['Page'],aggfunc='first')
```

But this obviously returns only the first value. Just to mention my dataset is huge (40 Million records..).

Thanks in advance if you can help me it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
df.groupby('CustId').Page.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).fillna('')
Out[729]: 
        0  1  2
CustId         
111     A  B   
222     A      
333     A  B  C
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, it's perfect. I now need to count how many customers for each permutation but i will have a go.

Comment: @tezzaaa yw :-) if you have any problem about it , you can come to me or this site again one of us will definitely help you out

Comment: Hi, I've add a go, i can almost get there with: df2.groupby(df2.columns, as_index=False).sum() but it does not return the count for each combination (obviously in this little example the count is 1 for each but in reality I will have many records/counts in my dataset. TY. (DF2 is the dataframe returned from applying your solution)

Comment: @tezzaaa I think it should be df2.groupby(df2.columns, as_index=False).size()

Comment: Thks :-) the problem is i would need the total for each actual combination as opposed to the column names 0,1,2: I would need an output like A|B|1 ; A|1 ; A|B|C|1 (each semi column being a different line in the dataframe)

Comment: @tezzaaa can you show me the sample data and your expected output again ?